# Div wrap in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm trying to wrap my list with div, here is my Thymeleaf structure:

```
<th:block th:if="${predStatus.namePrem}">
    <div class="Holder">
            <ul id="holder" class="price-table__info">
                <li>
                    <p class="exam1" th:text="#{exam2}"></p>
                </li>
            </ul>
</th:block>
        <ul id="holder" class="price-table__info">
            <li>
                <p th:unless="${predStatus.kom}" class="top" th:text="#{usp}"></p>
                <p th:if="${predStatus.kom}" class="top" th:text="#{usp1}"></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

What I trying to achieve is this structure

```
<div class="Holder">
   <ul id="holder" class="price-table__info">
      <li>
        <p class="top">Title 1</p>      
      </li>
   </ul>
  <ul id="holder" class="price-table__info">
     <li>
        <p class="top">Title 2</p>
     </li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following?
Just put the condition in the div

```
<div class="Holder" th:if="${predStatus.namePrem}">
            <ul id="holder" class="price-table__info">
                <li>
                    <p class="exam1" th:text="#{exam2}"></p>
                </li>
            </ul>

        <ul id="holder" class="price-table__info">
            <li>
                <p th:unless="${predStatus.kom}" class="top" th:text="#{usp}"></p>
                <p th:if="${predStatus.kom}" class="top" th:text="#{usp1}"></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```